Build Error in Ionic Capacitor App When Upgrading Google Play Services from 19.7.0 to 20.0.0
I'm working on an Ionic Capacitor project, and I've been using Google Play Services version 19.7.0 without any issues. However, when I try to upgrade to version 20.0.0, I'm encountering a build error that prevents the build from completing.
Details:
Ionic Version: 7.2.0
Capacitor Version: 6.0.0
Google Play Services Version: 19.7.0 (working) -> 20.0.0 (not working)
Gradle Version: 7.0.1
Android Studio Version: 2.1
Java Version: 21.0.3
What I've Tried:
Reverting back to Google Play Services version 19.7.0, which works without issues.
Cleaning the project and rebuilding.
Updating all related dependencies and Gradle files.
Checking compatibility with Capacitor plugins.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
